# Submit Form Programmatically React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to submit my for inside the handleSubmit function in react. I want to prefetch some information just before submitting the form and add to the form so I need to handle it insde the handle submit function. I am failing to trigger the submission after I am done with the operations i need to do. Can someone assist me with this?

I tried `evt.currentTarget.submit()` but its telling submit is not a function.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const CheckoutPayfastComponent: React.FC = () => {
useEffect(() => {
});

const handleSubmit = (evt: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    evt.preventDefault();        
    evt.currentTarget.action = "https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process";
    // trigger submit here
}

return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST" id="checkout"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="cell_number" value="0823456789"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" value="1"></input>

            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="550.00"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="General Plan"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="subscription_type" value="1"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="billing_date" value="2020-07-04"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="recurring_amount" value="550.00"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="frequency" value="4"></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="cycles" value="0"></input>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit" ></input>
        </form>

    </div>
    );
}

 export { CheckoutPayfastComponent };
```

Comment: Why don't you use Formik for handling form? If you need to pull data why don't you do that in useEffect?

Comment: I am fairly new to React. I see doing it in the useEffect actually does the trick

Comment: you can use following doc as reference: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview

Comment: have you thought about using **Axios** or **fetch** to submit the data?

Comment: I was using fetch. The thing I was struggling with is that, the external API I am sending to requires the call to be done as a form. So its expecting data like <form> //form elements here </form> and I got stuck on how to achieve that. Maybe you can assist @Cels

Comment: If you are still on this @Tatenda, you can have a look at form data. I'll try to draft you an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FormData` to submit the form
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

```
const CheckoutPayfastComponent: React.FC = () => {

const [myForm, setMyFormData] = useState({})

const handleSubmit = (evt: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    evt.preventDefault();        
    evt.currentTarget.action = "https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/process";
    // trigger submit here

    let formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(myForm).forEach(formName=>{
       formData.append(formName, myForm[formName]);
    });

    fetch("api/to/submit/my/formdata", {
        body: formData,
        method: "post"
    });
}

const onInputChange = (evt)=>{
  setMyFormData({[evt.target.name]: evt.target.value})
}

return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST" id="checkout"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="cell_number" value="0823456789" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="email_confirmation" value="1" onChange={onInputChange}></input>

            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="550.00" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="General Plan" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="subscription_type" value="1" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="billing_date" value="2020-07-04" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="recurring_amount" value="550.00" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="frequency" value="4" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="cycles" value="0" onChange={onInputChange}></input>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit" onChange={onInputChange}></input>
        </form>

    </div>
    );
}

 export { CheckoutPayfastComponent };
```

Comment: I will try this and give feedback